# Error: Exception in thread “main” java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, linked-list, runtime-error, binary-search-tree

This is a code of Java Binary Search Tree from a file. The code is creating a binary search tree from the csv file. But I have the error when I run this code. is says.

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextElement(StringTokenizer.java:407)
at binarytree.Node.<init>(Node.java:28)
at binarytree.BinaryTree.main(BinaryTree.java:241)**
```

Here is the code for Node for String:

```
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    public class Node {

    String key;
    int value;

    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(String line )
    {
        // parse the string into variables
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," ");

        this.key= st.nextElement().toString();
        this.value = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    }

    Node(String key, int value) {

            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return key + " " + value;
    }

 }
```

And here is code for the tree that includes insert, search and sort.

```
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

public class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    int MAX = 0;
    int MIN = 0;

    /***
* Add Node to the tree
*@param Country Name
*@param Population
     */
    public void addNode(String key, int value) {

        // Create a new Node and initialize it
        Node newNode = new Node(key, value);

        // If  no root this will become root
        if (root == null) {

            root = newNode;

        } else {

            // Set root as the Node and start  traversing the tree
            Node focusNode = root;

            // Future parent for new Node
            Node parent;

            while (true) {

                // root is the top parent 
                parent = focusNode;

        // Check if the new node should go on the left of parent
                if (key.compareToIgnoreCase(focusNode.key) < 0) {
                    // focus to the left child
                    focusNode = focusNode.left;

                    // If the left child has no children
                    if (focusNode == null) {

                        // then place the new node on the left of it
                        parent.left = newNode;
                        return; 
                    }

                } else { 
                    // If we get here put the node on the right
                    focusNode = focusNode.right;

                    // If the right child has no children
                    if (focusNode == null) {

                        // then place the new node on the right of it
                        parent.right = newNode;
                        return; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /***
* Order the tree ascending by key
*@param node
*@return
     */
    public Node orderTreeByCountry(Node node)
    {
        if(node != null)
        {
            orderTreeByCountry(node.left);
            System.out.println(node);
            orderTreeByCountry(node.right);
        }

        return node;
    }

    /***
* Find node by providing key name
*@param Node
*@return Node
     */
    public Node findNode(String key) {

        // Start at the top of the tree
        Node focusNode = root;

        // While node not found keep looking
        while (focusNode.key.compareToIgnoreCase(key) != 0) {

            // If we should search to the left
            if (key.compareToIgnoreCase(focusNode.key) < 0) {
                // Shift the focus Node to the left child
                focusNode = focusNode.left;

            } else {

                // Shift the focus Node to the right child
                focusNode = focusNode.right;
            }

            // The node wasn't found
            if (focusNode == null)
                return null;
        }
        return focusNode;
    }

    /***
* Get the value of node with specific key
*@param key
*@return Value
     */
    public int getValueForKey(String key)
    {
        // Start at the top of the tree
                Node focusNode = root;

                // While node not found
                while (focusNode.key.compareToIgnoreCase(key) != 0) {

                    // If we should search to the left
                    if (key.compareToIgnoreCase(focusNode.key) < 0) {
                        // Shift the focus Node to the left child
                        focusNode = focusNode.left;

                    } else {

                        // Shift the focus Node to the right child
                        focusNode = focusNode.right;
                    }

                    // The node wasn't found
                    if (focusNode == null)
                        return -1;
                }
                return focusNode.value;
    }

    /***
* Get how many nodes in the tree
*@param node
*@return number of nodes
     */
    public int getNodesCount(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null) {

            return 0;

        } else {

            int count = 1;

            count  +=  getNodesCount(node.left);
            count  += getNodesCount(node.right); 

            return count;
        }
    }

    /***
* Get min value for tree which is based on key, value attributes
*@param node
*@return min value
     */
    public int getMinValue(Node node)
    {   
        if(node != null)
        {   
            getMinValue(node.left); 

            if(MIN == 0 ) {
                MIN = node.value;
            }

            if(MIN > node.value) {
                MIN = node.value;
            }

            getMinValue(node.right);
        }

        return MIN;
    }

    /***
* Get max value for tree which is based on key, value attributes
*@param node
*@return max value
     */
    public int getMaxValue(Node node)
    {
        if(node != null)
        {   
            getMaxValue(node.left); 

            if(MAX == 0 ) {
                MAX = node.value;
            }

            if(MAX < node.value) {
                MAX = node.value;
            }

            getMaxValue(node.right);
        }

        return MAX;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader br;
        BinaryTree btree = new BinaryTree();

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new 
        FileReader("C:\\Users\\8Users\\Desktop/countries.txt"));
            String line = "";

             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 

                    /*Create Country node from the line */
                    Node country = new Node(line); 

                    btree.addNode(country.key, country.value);          
                }

             br.close();

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        btree.orderTreeByCountry(btree.root);

        System.out.println("Number of Countries is : " + 
        btree.getNodesCount(btree.root));

        System.out.println("Min Population is : " + 
        btree.getMinValue(btree.root));

        System.out.println("Max Population is : " + 
        btree.getMaxValue(btree.root));

        int population = btree.getValueForKey("xxx");

       if(population== -1)
            System.out.println("Sorry this Country is not in this btree");
        else
            System.out.println("Population is : " + population);

    }

}
```

Hope u guys can help me solve this problem :(

Comment: how your file look like, what information you have?

Comment: Looks like the `line` does not contain any space and hence, there is no second token.

Comment: @YCF_L in csv file. It contains the name of countries and the population of the country.

Comment: @DarshanMehta what do you mean by there is no second token? I'm sorry I'm still learning programming.

Comment: @LittlePotato try printing `line` to console and see which value the application throws Exception for.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the implementation of nextToken()methon in  java.util. StringTokenizer class which is as follows :

```
    public String nextToken() {
        this.currentPosition = this.newPosition >= 0 && !this.delimsChanged ? this.newPosition: this.skipDelimiters(this.currentPosition);
        this.delimsChanged = false;
        this.newPosition = -1;
        if (this.currentPosition >= this.maxPosition) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            int arg0 = this.currentPosition;
            this.currentPosition = this.scanToken(this.currentPosition);
            return this.str.substring(arg0, this.currentPosition);
        }
    }
```

as you can see above method throw  **NoSuchElementException** "if (this.currentPosition >= this.maxPosition) "
So There must some problem inside your input file "C:\Users\8Users\Desktop/countries.txt".